# Managed Object Not Supported?

Tags: soql, managed-package, exception

I an running into this System.QueryException:

> sObject type 'Meet_Up__DemoCandidate__corder' is not supported.
>
> If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Why do I get this error? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

```
Meet_Up__DemoCandidate__corder__c
```

You are missing to append __c .As it is needed for custom objects whenever you refer in code